# Get closest date and calculate time difference

Tags: php, date

I got a form that passes vars via javascript to an external php file to process it.

One var is e.g.: 30.03.2015 11:14

That particular variable needs to be compared to four other dates:

1: march 31st
2: june 30th
3: september 30th
4: december 31st

The year of course can change, therefore the four dates do not include a year and the year in the passed variable needs to be ignored as well as the hours and minutes.

I need to know which of those four dates is closest to the passed variable and also how many days is between the past variable and the closest date of the four dates in the string.

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Hi Jay. The problem is already solved. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each of the target dates into a day of the year value (0 to 365):

```
$mar = date('z', strtotime('March 31st'));
$jun = date('z', strtotime('June 30th'));
$sep = date('z', strtotime('September 30th'));
$dec = date('z', strtotime('December 31st'));
```

You can convert the incoming date to the same format:

```
$date = '30.03.2015 11:14';
$day = date('z', strtotime($date));
```

You can calculate the days between each target date easily:

```
$mar_days = abs($day-$mar);
```

Doing that for each of the target dates, will give you a "days to target" for each target date. From there, you can decide what you want to do. You may decide that you want only "closest to without passing". There is a lot of vagueness in your question.

Comment: Looking good! thanks! I dont know what vagueness is in my question that doesnt help you answering it. But this seems to be what I am looking for. The reason I need to compare the four dates to the first one is to eventually calculate a prices based on the amount of days between those two. 
Now I know which dates are closest and based on that can calculate a price.

Comment: "Days between" is vague. For example April 1 is one day after March 31, but you might say it is closes to June 30 because it is after March 31 and you don't want negative days. If you do allow negative days, how to you want to handle Jan 1? This will say it is closes to March 31 because comparing to Dec 31 will be 364 days apart. You can force a fix by checking `abs(365+$day-$dec)` to see if it is closest. Overall, there is a lot of customization possibilities.

Comment: That is a very good point yes. I do not want negative days. April 1st is indeed closest to March 31st but is not allowed. How would you approach that? Only positive values are allowed. So April 1st is closest to June 30th.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kainaw I got the answer. Slightly adapted to my situation only to use positive values:

```
$mar = date('z', strtotime('March 31st'));
$jun = date('z', strtotime('June 30th'));
$sep = date('z', strtotime('September 30th'));
$dec = date('z', strtotime('December 31st'));
$date = '01.07.2015 11:14';
$day = date('z', strtotime($date));
$mar_days = $mar-$day;
$jun_days = $jun-$day;
$sep_days = $sep-$day;
$dec_days = $dec-$day;
$values = array($mar_days,$jun_days,$sep_days,$dec_days);
$values = array_filter($values, function($v) { return $v >= 0; });
$days = min($values);
echo $days;
```